# C++ How to remove double quotes in char

Tags: c++, replace, char

I want to remove double-quotes from a string, for example `13.3" Rentina` becomes `13.3 Rentina`

```
const char* s = sheet->readStr(row, col);
int ii = strlen(s);
char* b;
b=(char*)s;

char ch;
for (int i = 0; i < ii ;++i) {
  strncpy(&ch, b+ii, 1);
  if(ch == '\"'){
    ch = '\"';
    memcpy(b+i, &ch, 1);
  }
}

myfile << b;
```

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: What your code suffers from?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you could try using std::string::replace

Comment: i try replace quotes in char c++

Comment: Your description makes it appear more like you want to _remove_ quotes, not replace them (unless you mean replace them with empty space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do `b=(char*)s`!!!

The compiler lets you in on this one, but you will get a runtime exception as soon as you attempt to write into the memory address space pointed by `b`.

The variable `s` is **possibly** pointing to an address in the code-section, which is a read-only memory address space within your program ("possibly", because perhaps that `const` declaration of `s` is just something you added on your own initiative).

You should allocate a new `char` array, and copy the output string into that array instead.

So first of all, change the above statement to `b = (char*)malloc(strlen(s))`.

In addition, do not pass to `strncpy` (or any other `str` function for that matter) an address of a `char` variable. These functions operate on `char` arrays, and either assume that the array ends with a 0 character, or set the character at the end of the array to 0.

You can try the following piece of code (assuming that your purpose is to remove the `'"'`):

```
const char* s = sheet->readStr(row, col);
int ii = strlen(s);
char* b = (char*)malloc(ii+1);
if (b != NULL)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0,j=0; i<ii; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != '"')
            b[j++] = s[i];
    }
    b[j] = 0;
    // Add your code here (do whatever you wanna do with 'b')
    free(b);
}
else
{
    printf("Out of memory\n");
}
```

Comment: "You cannot do b=(char*)s!!!" - actually this depends on what `sheet->readStr(row, col);` returns. If it returns a pointer to writable space then it is quite fine to write that space through `b`, it doesn't matter if the address was converted to `const char *` and then back to `char *` in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with strings in C++, you should use character arrays and functions like strncpy only when you have a strong reason to use them. By default you should use standard string, which makes e.g. memory management much easier. The solution to your problem with std::string is

```
std::string s = sheet->readStr(row, col);  
size_t pos = 0;
while ((pos = s.find('"', pos)) != std::string::npos)
    s = s.erase(pos, 1);
myfile << s;
```

Comment: thanks you !! it is working. but have problem with encoding.  example my record in utf-8. when i got result "TT","TГЄn sбєЈn phбє","Bб»™ vi xб»­ lГ. Can you help me !! thanks you very much